# Problemas para escrever em um input a partir do controller

Tags: php, laravel-5

Olá, estou com problemas para inserir os dados a partir do controller.

Estou fazendo as atividades de um livro de Laravel da Casa do Código para aprender e precisei fazer isso para atualizar o registro de uma tupla do banco, acabei usando o seguinte workaround:

```
<input name="nome" class="form-control" value="{{$p->nome}}" />
```

Funcionou, contudo, no livro, o autor ensina a manter os dados no formulário durante um erro de validação usando o seguinte código:

```
<input name="nome" class="form-control" value="{{ old('nome') }}" />
```

Isso quebrou meu esquema de atribuir direto no value os atributos do objeto que vem do banco... Assim, terei que adicionar os valores nos inputs do formulário via controller durante a atualização de dados.

Pesquisei em vários lugares, até encontrei alguma referência, mas não consegui usá-las devido a falta do namespace que deveria importar.

Desde já, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver esse problema faça:

```
<input name="nome" class="form-control" value="{{ isset($p) ? $p->nome : old('nome') }}" />
```

no caso vai funcionar assim, se o objeto `$p` tiver setado ele trará os dados do *atributo* nome, se não ele pega o dado se tiver da *última requisição*.

Comment: Obrigado! Não conhecia este método isset($var). Sou novo em PHP, rs.